# How to predict the output for new data with the model tested already?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am pretty new to data analysis using Python. I tried code which I learned for Logistic Regression.

I need help on the below.

1. The code predicted and I am now seeing the accuracy level using the last line. But how can I output the Predicted column along with the other columns.
2. Now the data i used is for 2016. I have a new data for 2017. Now what should i do to predict for the entire 2017 data. (I am sorry I have no clue on how to use this model to predict the new data received)

```py
"""
#   coding: utf-8

#   Logistic Regression - Click Predictor
# 
#   In this Use Case we will be working with a fake advertising data set, indicating whether or not a particular internet user clicked on an Advertisement on a company website. 
# 
#   With this data, we will try to create a model that will predict whether or not they will click on an ad based off the features of that user.
# 
#   This data set contains the following features:
# 
#   * 'Daily Time Spent on Site': consumer time on site in minutes
#   * 'Age': cutomer age in years
#   * 'Area Income': Avg. Income of geographical area of consumer
#   * 'Daily Internet Usage': Avg. minutes a day consumer is on the internet
#   * 'Ad Topic Line': Headline of the advertisement
#   * 'City': City of consumer
#   * 'Male': Whether or not consumer was male
#   * 'Country': Country of consumer
#   * 'Timestamp': Time at which consumer clicked on Ad or closed window
#   * 'Clicked on Ad': 0 or 1 indicated clicking on Ad

"""


# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')


# Get the Data
# Read in the advertising.csv file and set it to a data frame called ad_data.
ad_data = pd.read_csv('D:\\DS\\Logistic Regression Algorithm\\Python\\advertising.csv')
ad_data.head()


# Use info and describe() on ad_data
ad_data.info()
ad_data.describe()




# Exploratory Data Analysis
# Let's use seaborn to explore the data!  
# Try recreating the plots shown below!
# Create a histogram of the Age**

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ad_data['Age'].hist(bins=30)
plt.xlabel('Age')


# Create a jointplot showing Area Income versus Age.
sns.jointplot(x='Age',y='Area Income',data=ad_data)

# Create a jointplot of 'Daily Time Spent on Site' vs. 'Daily Internet Usage'
sns.jointplot(x='Daily Time Spent on Site',y='Daily Internet Usage',data=ad_data,color='green')

# Finally, create a pairplot with the hue defined by the 'Clicked on Ad' column feature.**
sns.pairplot(ad_data,hue='Clicked on Ad',palette='bwr')




# Logistic Regression
# Now it's time to do a train test split, and train our model!
# You'll have the freedom here to choose columns that you want to train on!
# Split the data into training set and testing set using train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = ad_data[['Daily Time Spent on Site', 'Age', 'Area Income','Daily Internet Usage', 'Male']]
y = ad_data['Clicked on Ad']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.22, random_state=42)


# Train and fit a logistic regression model on the training set.
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)


# Predictions and Evaluations
# Now predict values for the testing data.
predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)


# Create a classification report for the model.
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))


prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('D:\\DS\\prediction.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to 1st question:

```
ad_data['predictions'] = predictions
print(ad_data.head())
```

Just add another column named as `predictions` in original dataset.

answer to 2nd question:

```
data_2017 = pd.read_csv(data_path)
test_predictions = logmodel.predict(data_2017[['Daily Time Spent on Site', 'Age', 'Area Income','Daily Internet Usage', 'Male']])
```

This will work only if, test data pf 2017 have columns as same name as in data 2016 used for training.

**Edited**

to add the predictions and export

```
data_2017["predictions"] = test_predictions

data_2017.to_csv(path)
```

Comment: I predicted the new data but now how should export the result along with the other columns. New data is not having the predicted column. so we have to export the result with the new data columns + predicted column.. Please help

Comment: @Vijay please check

Answer (score 0):

> The code predicted and I am now seeing the accuracy level using the last line. But how can I output the Predicted column along with the other columns.

I imagine that you want something like this:

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x_test': X_test, 'y_test': y_test,'predictions': predictions}).to_csv('D:\\DS\\prediction.csv')
```

> Now the data i used is for 2016. I have a new data for 2017. Now what should i do to predict for the entire 2017 data. (I am sorry I have no clue on how to use this model to predict the new data received)

For this one you only need to pass the new data to predict to the predict method, as your model will be already trained and ready to predict with unseen data .So something similar to this:

```
x_data_2017 = #your new data for 2017
predictions_2017 = logmodel.predict(x_data_2017)
```

Comment: I am getting the below error when i run the first code.

ValueError: array length 220 does not match index length 1000

Comment: Oh my bad probably, I assumed that data from all columns had the same length, otherwise `DataFrame.from_dict()` will return that error. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for prompt replies. Still getting some other error and I am not able to understand it.


  File "C:\Users\kumarv3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1691, in construction_error
    passed, implied))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 3), indices imply (220, 3)

Comment: Without having more background and seeing the code I can't tell exactly, but to me it feels like the error is in the prediction and not in the creation of the DataFrame. Is it possible that the previous dataset you used to predict `X_test` had size (220,3) and the new one has size (5,3)? If that's the difference maybe trying with a dataset of the same size will help.

Comment: I tried but not sure how to find the Predicted row count. I managed to find the x_test row count and it is 220. But not able to find the predicted row count

Comment: `predictions.shape()` should work to get the shape of the predicted output

Comment: For predictions.shape I am getting TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Now I predicted the 2017 data. How should I export the results along with the predicted column